# remote assistance - it needs to be very selective

Tags: networking, remote-assistance

Windows XP - SP3 laptop
Windows 7 Home Desktop

I need the Windows 7 desktop to help out windows xp whenever it's needed without doing anything much on xp computer (because the person who uses xp laptop these days is not very tech-proficient.)

Both computers are wired together and intranet of their own going, while they are both wirelessly connected to internet. I want to make sure xp laptop always allows access to Windows 7 (without a need to initiate the invitation, but I guess I could make the invitation never expire or something like that? Will restarting the XP laptop kill the open invitation thing though?) XP laptop should also always disallow remote assistance from any other computer that is not on the network.

I don't have to use Remote Assistance if you know of a freeware that can better accomplish the task.

Comment: Ideas. Use lesser known VNC programs to remote, instead of a service hole that remains running. Shut off the whole service when uneeded using Net Stop/start commands. Avoid the web entirely via wired USB laplink KVMs. Or you can restrict Remote Assistance via Group Policy and specify various levels of permissions such as only allowing Remote Assistance from within the corporate firewall. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx Check it out so many ways to access , it is no wonder why it is patched over and over again. Plus the other connection needed to be avail.

Comment: Windows XP Home or Professional?  With XP Pro you can set up and use Remote Desktop.

Comment: @Psycogeek Do you know of a free VNC that lets me specify "let it connect only if it's part of wired network?" I have home edition, so I dont think I have access to group policies.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I have Windows XP Media Center Edition

Comment: @progtick most of the (more freeware style) VNCs will allow you to restrict the "IP" that can be connected, although it might be hard to find in its options, and unintuitive. So you can disable a password requirement, allow only one connection (by whatever name they call it) and restrict to a specific IP address or range.  .  I really think the way we used them is "best" only run the program, when needed. each side has a handy dandy shortcut , and apon the need for remoting, the program is run, at all other times the ability to connect , does not exist , and therfore the hole is not left open.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Remote Dekstop on the XP computer.  Note that the user account on the XP computer must have a password.

Taken from [Microsoft Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315328):

1. Click **Start**, and then right-click **My Computer**.
2. On the shortcut menu that appears, click **Properties**.
3. Click the **Remote** tab, and then click to select the **Allow users to connect remotely to this computer** check box.
4. When you are prompted to confirm this change, click **OK**.
5. Click **Select Remote Users**, and then click **Add** to specify additional user accounts to be granted remote access. **NOTE:** Administrators are automatically granted remote access privileges.
6. When you are finished adding user accounts, click **OK**. Make sure that the account that is being added does actually exist on the remote computer. If the account does not exist on the remote computer, create it.
7. Click **OK**, and then click **OK** again.

On the Windows 7 computer:

1. Click **Start**, and navigate to **All Programs**, **Accessories**, **Remote Desktop Connection**.
2. In the **Computer** field, type the name or IP address of the XP computer.
3. Press **Connect**.
4. Type in the login credentials for the XP computer.

One more tip, now that the XP computer has a password where it may not have previously, you can set up auto-login.

1. Press **Win+R** on the keyboard.
2. Type `control userpasswords2` and press **Run**.
3. Clear the tick next to **Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.** and press **OK**.
4. Type the username and password for the user account you usually use.

The next time you reboot the XP computer, it will log in to the desktop immediately.